# How to display the study program name according to the study program id in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, database

I have a student list table. In the table, there is a column to display study programs. This column retrieves data from the study program database. However, what is displayed in the table is the study program id. What I want is that the study program column can display the name of the study program based on the id. How can I change the syntax in my code?

This is model

```
public function prodi()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Prodi::class, 'prodi');
}

public function toSearchableArray(): array
{
    return [
        'nama' => $this->nama,
        'nim' => $this->nim,
    ];
}
```

}

This is controller

```
public function index(Request $request)
{
    if ($request->keyword) {
        $mahasiswa = Mahasiswa::where('is_delete', null)->search($request->keyword)->paginate(PHP_INT_MAX);
    } else {
        $mahasiswa = Mahasiswa::where('is_delete', null)->paginate(PHP_INT_MAX);
    }

    //return view('mahasiswa.daftar_mahasiswa')->with('mahasiswa', $mahasiswa);

    return view('mahasiswa.daftar_mahasiswa', compact('mahasiswa'));
}

public function create()
{
    $prodis = Prodi::get();
    return view('mahasiswa.tambah_daftar_mahasiswa', compact('prodis'));
}


public function store(Request $request)
{
    $mahasiswa = new Mahasiswa;
    $mahasiswa->nim = $request->nim;
    $mahasiswa->nama = $request->nama;
    $mahasiswa->prodi = $request->prodi;
    $mahasiswa->j_kel = $request->j_kel;
    $mahasiswa->save();

    return redirect()->route('mahasiswa.index');
}

public function show($id)
{
    return view('mahasiswa.daftar_mahasiswa-detail', [
        'mahasiswa' => Mahasiswa::findOrFail($id),
    ]);
}

public function edit($id)
{
    $mahasiswa = Mahasiswa::findOrFail($id);
    $prodis = Prodi::all(); // Mengambil semua data program studi

    return view('mahasiswa.edit_daftar_mahasiswa', compact('mahasiswa', 'prodis'));
}

public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
    $mahasiswa = Mahasiswa::find($id);

    $mahasiswa->update([
        'nim' => $request->get('nim'),
        'nama' => $request->get('nama'),
        'j_kel' => $request->get('j_kel'),
    ]);

    Alert::success('Berhasil ', 'Berhasil mengubah data mahasiswa');
    return redirect()->route('mahasiswa.index');
}

public function destroy($id)
{
    $mahasiswa = Mahasiswa::findOrfail($id);
    // $mahasiswa->delete();
    $mahasiswa->update([
        'is_delete' => 'deleted',
    ]);

    Alert::success('Berhasil ', 'Berhasil menghapus data mahasiswa');

    return redirect()->route('mahasiswa.index');
}

public function exportpdf()
{
    $datas = Mahasiswa::all();
    $pdf = Pdf::loadView('mahasiswa.pdf', ['datas' => $datas]);

    return $pdf->download('Data Mahasiswa -' . Carbon::now()->format('Y-m-d') . '.pdf');
}
```

}

This is view

```
<tbody>
                @foreach ($mahasiswa as $mhs)
                    <tr>
                        <td>{{ $loop->iteration }}</td>
                        <td>{{ $mhs->nama }}</td>
                        <td>{{ $mhs->nim }}</td>
                        <td>{{ $mhs->prodi }}</td>
                        <td>{{ $mhs->j_kel }}</td>
                        <td class="d-flex justify-content-around">
                            <button class="action" style="background: #3C91E6">
                                <a href="{{ route('mahasiswa.show', $mhs->nim) }}" style="color: inherit">
                                    <i class='bx bxs-detail'></i>
                                    Detail
                                </a>
                            </button>
                            <button class="action" style="background: #ff8200">
                                <a href="{{ route('mahasiswa.edit', $mhs->nim) }}" style="color: inherit">
                                    <i class='bx bxs-edit'></i>
                                    Edit
                                </a>
                            </button>
                            <form action="{{ route('mahasiswa.delete', $mhs->nim) }}" method="post">
                                @method('delete')
                                @csrf
                                <input name="_method" type="hidden" value="DELETE">
                                <button type="submit" class="action show_confirm" data-toggle="tooltip"
                                    style="background: #cc2936">
                                    <i class='bx bx-trash'></i>
                                    Hapus
                                </button>
                            </form>
                        </td>

                    </tr>
                @endforeach
            </tbody>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display the name of the study program instead of its ID, you only need to make changes in your blade file because you already defined the relationship in your model.

Instead of,

```
<td>{{ $mhs->prodi }}</td>
```

Write it like this,

```
<td>{{ $mhs->prodi->nama }}</td>
```

You have already defined a relationship in the model, so using the above syntax will return the name using dynamic relationship.

Comment: I still get this error "Attempt to read property "nama" on string". What it is mean?

Comment: that means prodi is "string" and not a collection. So try to use eager loading. Check docs -> [link](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading)